# Pulling aces from a split deck

Tags: combinatorics

I have a normal deck of 52.  I pull the aces, deal it in to 4 piles of 12, and put an ace in each pile.  I shuffle each pile like a monkey on meth.  I flip cards from one pile, and when I see its ace I switch to the next pile.  If I flip only 40 total cards, what are the odds I didn't see all of the aces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did it numerically in Excel.  I get about $0.952207556$  The chance of using $k$ cards for the first ace is $\frac 1{13}$ for $k \in [1,13]$  The chance of using $n$ cards for a subsequent ace is the sum of the chances of using $n-13$ to $n-1$ for the previous aces divided by $13$.  This yields easily to copy-right/copy-down.

Answer (score 1):

The ace is equally likely to be in position 1, 2, $\ldots$ 13 in each of the four piles. The generating function that counts the number of configurations of such positions that will require looking at $n$ cards before seeing all aces is
$$\left(\frac{x^{14}-1}{x-1}-1\right)^4.$$
Expanding and counting all coefficients of $x^n$ for $n\leq 40$ gives $27196$, for a total probability of
$$\frac{27196}{13^4} \approx 0.95.$$

Comment: Sorry for not picking the more correct math answer.  I'm a programmer.  An algorithm makes more sense to me.

Comment: No worries, pick the answer most helpful to you!

Comment: BTW I'm a programmer too, if you didn't learn about generating functions in Discrete Math you might want to read about them someday -- they're an incredibly powerful way of solving a lot of combinatorics problems.